# Trying to write a predicate gradeMap(L,R), where L is a list of percentage grade values, and R is a list of corresponding grade letters (a-f)

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a predicate gradeMap(L,R) where I provide a list of grades and it returns a list R containing the mapped grades. I was thinking of this like a map, I know what the base case is and I know how to recurse but I do not know how I will handle storing the respective alphabet grade for each percentage.

code is partial and hasn't been fully implemented (I am stuck).

```
 gradeMap(L,R).
 gradeMap([],[]). %base case 
 gradeMap([H|T],R):-
 %handle percentages
 recurse and add the grade to the list R
```

Desired Output:

```
?- gradeMap([0, 16, 49, 55, 63, 78, 92], R).
R=[f,f,f,d,c,b,a]
```

Comment: does every number have a specific alphabet?

Comment: yes @LuaiGhunim just like ordinary grading, so  below 50 would be f, 50-60 would be D, 60-70 would be C, 70-80 would be B, 80-100 would be A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gradeMap(L,R) :- maplist(grade,L,R).

grade(V,a) :- between(81,100,V).
grade(V,b) :- between(71,80,V).
grade(V,c) :- between(61,70,V).
grade(V,d) :- between(51,60,V).
grade(V,f) :- between(0,50,V).
```

or, if your Prolog doesn't have [between](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3)/3

```
grade(V,a) :- V>=81,V=<100.
... etc etc
```

*edit*

A problem of the between/3 approach is that's needless working only for integers.
Another problem, I did a poor choice for ranges. I would correct to

```
grade(V,a) :- V>=80.
grade(V,b) :- V>=70, V<80.
...
grade(V,f) :- V<50.
```

Comment: With 50% I get an f?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the use of CLP(FD) for this. You could define a predicate that describes the relation between percentages and letters and then use maplist/3 to describe a relation between a list of percentages and a list of letters:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(apply)).   % for maplist

percentage_letter(P,f) :-
   P in 0..49.
percentage_letter(P,d) :-
   P in 50..59.
percentage_letter(P,c) :-
   P in 60..69.
percentage_letter(P,b) :-
   P in 70..79.
percentage_letter(P,a) :-
   P in 80..100.

percentages_letters(P,L) :-
   maplist(percentage_letter,P,L).
```

I took the liberty of making the percentage ranges non-intersecting. Just adapt those to your needs. This predicate works both ways:

```
?- percentages_letters([0, 16, 49, 55, 63, 78, 92],L).
L = [f, f, f, d, c, b, a] ;
false.

?- percentages_letters(P,[f, f, f, d, c, b, a]).
P = [_G835, _G838, _G841, _G844, _G847, _G850, _G853],
_G835 in 0..49,
_G838 in 0..49,
_G841 in 0..49,
_G844 in 50..59,
_G847 in 60..69,
_G850 in 70..79,
_G853 in 80..100.
```

However, the letter-to-percentage direction yields residual goals since there are no unique solutions for the letters. If you want to get concrete values, you can use label(L).

```
?- percentages_letters(P,[f, f, f, d, c, b, a]), label(P).
P = [0, 0, 0, 50, 60, 70, 80] ;
P = [0, 0, 0, 50, 60, 70, 81] ;
P = [0, 0, 0, 50, 60, 70, 82] ;
P = [0, 0, 0, 50, 60, 70, 83] ;
P = [0, 0, 0, 50, 60, 70, 84] ;
P = [0, 0, 0, 50, 60, 70, 85] ;
P = [0, 0, 0, 50, 60, 70, 86] ;
P = [0, 0, 0, 50, 60, 70, 87] ;
.
.
.
```

The most general query produces all possible lists but enumerates them in an unfair way:

```
?- percentages_letters(P,L).
P = L, L = [] ;
P = [_G47],
L = [f],
_G47 in 0..49 ;
P = [_G75, _G78],
L = [f, f],
_G75 in 0..49,
_G78 in 0..49 ;
.
.
.
```

You can get a fair listing by prefixing a goal length:

```
?- length(P,_), percentages_letters(P,L).
P = L, L = [] ;
P = [_G48],
L = [f],
_G48 in 0..49 ;
P = [_G48],
L = [d],
_G48 in 50..59 ;
P = [_G48],
L = [c],
_G48 in 60..69 ;
.
.
.
P = [_G234, _G237],
L = [b, f],
_G234 in 70..79,
_G237 in 0..49 ;
.
.
.
P = [_G370, _G373, _G376, _G379],
L = [f, d, a, c],
_G370 in 0..49,
_G373 in 50..59,
_G376 in 80..100,
_G379 in 60..69 ;
.
.
.
```